# Casting LinkedListNode to object

Tags: c#, linked-list

My question is quite simple. I want to take a certain element from a C# LinkedList and cast it to desired type. How can I perform it? I have tried something like this but its not allowing me.

```
A old = (A)head.Next;
```

By the way `head` is `LinkedListNode<A>`

I have searched it but haven't found the related material yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `head` is a `LinkedListNode<A>`, then [`head.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be(v=vs.110).aspx) is also a `LinkedListNode<A>` as well.  There's no way a `LinkedListNode<A>` can be cast to a `A`, a `LinkedListNode` is a node, not the value of the node.

If you want to get the value at the node, then you need to call [`head.Value`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86397t7k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
A old = head.Value;
```

Comment: Thanks! So there isn't any cast available for this case?

Comment: There's no general way to convert a generic type to it's generic parameter.  It's easier to see with `List<T>`.  If `list` is a `List<int>` does `int a = (int)list` make any sense?  No list is a List of int's, not an int itself.  So by default there's no way for C# to allow this cast.  It would have been possible for `LinkListNode<T>` to define a conversion method so the cast would work, but they did not.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx

Comment: Thanks! This is much better explanation. I got it